# Market portfolio

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory

If I create portfolio consisting of three stocks and build efficient frontier for this portfolio and if there is a risk free rate for treasury bills and then I draw tangent line from risk free rate on vertical axis to the efficient frontier of graph, than what the tangent point will mean?